# Trouble Loading CSV content as opposed to Downloading

Tags: jquery, jsp

Good Afternoon,

With Yahoo Finance, following the following link, along with some convenient URL tags, will customize a downloadable CSV with nearly whatever stock information you like. The URL will automatically download a CSV to wherever your downloads default:

http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="GOOG"+&f="s"

I, however, do not want to download this content on to my computer, I would like to download it into a webpage. Here is what I've been toying with:

The JSP, index.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE JSP>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/script.js"></script>
<style>
#Generic_Container {
height:500px;
width:500px;
background-color:transparent;
}
#Link1 {
width:200px;
height:200px;
position:absolute;
top:5px;
left:5px;
background-color:blue;
color:white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Generic_Container">
    <a href='http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="GOOG"+&f="s"' id='Link1'></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the related file, script.js (poor naming conventions, I realize; however, this example is for inquisitive purposes alone):

```
$('document').ready(function() {

$('#Link1').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#Link1').load('http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="GOOG"+&f="s"');
});

});
```

this should prevent the download of the file from the site, and instead load the content into the frame, but I must be doing something wrong. I'm also open to alternative methods of getting this done, if I'm indeed doing something not-so-logical..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest using Yahoo's YQL AJAX proxy service to return the data as jsonp and parse it to html from there. The YQL sandbox console has examples how to retrieve quotes

[YQL Console Quote Example](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22YHOO%22,%22AAPL%22,%22GOOG%22,%22MSFT%22%29)

Once you get the url set up in console, can use `$.getJSON` to retrieve the data.

Other option is to use a proxy on your own server that retrieves the csv using CURL and parses to html or json for you to retrive with AJAX